# iPhone - Overwriting existing HTML pages with most recently loaded pages from internet

Tags: html, uiwebview, iphone, updating

following is the summary of my requirement

### Requirement :

Steps:

NOTE: I already have a page "abc.html" (but it may have outdated contents)

1. check for internet connectivity
2. If the internet connection NOT is available:

   1. load the page "abc.html" from resource folder (inside app)

   If the internet connection is available:

   1. get the link to the "abc.html" page (that is on webserver)
   2. load the existing page "abc.html" from web server
   3. **meanwhile store the new abc.html (on web server) into the app**
   4. notify the user and reload the page
   5. ***update the "abc.html" with the HTML page downloaded from Internet***

### What I have done till now:

1. I have checked whether the internet connection is available using Reachability
2. Also I am able to show the existing "abc.html" page in UIWebView.

### What I am seeking:

I want to know How can I replace (overwrite/ update) this existing "abc.html" page with the one that is just loaded into UIwebView (the one on web-server).

Also If you have a better way to achieve this functionality . please feel free to suggest.

Thank you

### EDIT:

I want to use ASIHTTPREquest to achieve this (ASI DataCache)... please guide

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, but you could take a look at `NSURLCache`.

If you subclass `NSURLCache`, you get to control where the web view will load its data from in the `cachedResponseForRequest:` method.
The cache also holds any images the web page might download, so you can provide the full page content, even without a connection.

Comment: now I am trying to download he file using ASIHTTPRequest. UIWebView will load the same file but if request object is able to contact o internet and get a new page. It will update the file and will tell webview to refresh. but I do not know much how will I accomplish this idea